# applet showing random sum result

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

I have to take 2 number from user and print the result. Sometime it get correct result but mostly its wrong. My code is same as shown in a tutorial but result is not correct. Please Help to solve problem This is my first applet.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

///*<applet code="MyApplet" width="300" height="200"></applet> */ 
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
    Label l1,l2,l3;
    TextField t1,t2;
    Button b1;

    public void init(){
        l1=new Label("First Number"); // Inputing fist number
        l2=new Label("Second Number"); //Inputing second nunber
        l3=new Label("---------------"); // Displaying Result
        t1=new TextField();
        t2=new TextField();
        b1=new Button("Add");
        setLayout(null);
        l1.setBounds(50, 50, 100,20);
        l2.setBounds(30, 100, 100, 20);
        t1.setBounds(150, 50, 100, 20);
        t2.setBounds(150, 100, 100, 20);
        b1.setBounds(100, 150, 80, 20);
        l3.setBounds(100, 180, 100, 20);
        add(l1);
        add(t1);
        add(l2);
        add(t2);
        add(b1);
        add(l3);
        b1.addActionListener(new MyHandler());
    }

    public class MyHandler implements ActionListener{   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int a,b,s;
            a=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()); // first number
            b=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()); // second number
            s=a+b;
            l3.setText("Sum is "+s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record : you understand that java applets are dead end technology and not really worth learning?

Answer (score 0):

The applet shows the wrong result because there is a typo in your handler:

```
b=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()); // second number
```

Should be `t2`, not `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another problem of turning the int back to string
in that case use     .toString()

```
int number = -782;
String numberAsString = intInstance.toString();
```